# Clojure Trigonometry

Tags: math, clojure, trigonometry

In 2014, where do I get Clojure trigonometry functions like sin and atan2 ?

I see some of contrib.math is now in https://clojure.github.io/math.numeric-tower/ but that doesn't seem to have these functions.

Answer (score 24):

You can call functions in the [Java Math class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) from Clojure.

Java: `Math.sin(x)`

Clojure: `(Math/sin x)`

Comment: Is math.numeric-tower just a wrapper around Java Math? And if so, any idea why it doesn't support all the Java Math functions?

Answer (score 2):

The [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) statistical package for Clojure includes `acos`, `asin`, `atan`, `atan2`, `cos`, `sin`, and `tan`, along with many other potentially useful mathematical functions.